# How to alphabetize an ordered linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list, sorting, linked-list

I'm having so much trouble with a program I'm working.

The program is supposed to print out the elements of an ordered linked list (as in there are no setters available for the list) in alphabetical order. Here's what I have:

GOrderedList is the node, Event is the value. I had the idea to attempt to find the words and place them in an arraylist alphabetically.

```
public static ArrayList <String> sortEvents (GOrderedList <Event> C){

    //create arraylist 
    ArrayList <String>  sortedList = new ArrayList <String>(); 

    while (C.getNext()!=null){
        GOrderedList <Event> first = C.getNext();
        String highest = first.getValue().getname(); 

        while (first.getNext()!=null){
        if (first.getNext().getValue().getname().compareTo(highest)<0){
            highest=C.getNext().getValue().getname(); 
            }
            first=first.getNext(); 
        }
        sortedList.add(highest);
        C = C.getNext(); 
    }
```

This is producing the list -which is encouraging - but it is out of order. I had the idea of placing the elements in the new ArrayList in alphabetical order. I could place the items in the ArrayList and then sort it, but I would rather not do that.

Comment: It is producing the wrong output? What kind of output does it produce? What output did you expect?

Comment: What is the hierarchy of GOrderedList? Can you not use Collections.sort() ?

Comment: Excuse me, with the information you have given, we have no chance of helping you. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Is that the `GOrderedList` from NYU Computer Science? [link](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/DataStructures/SampleCode/GOrderedList/GOrderedList.java)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Sorry about that, some of my original post got deleted and I didn't notice. I've updated the question. And yes, it is the GOrderedList,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comparator to sort it .Like below.

```
public static ArrayList<String> sortEvents(GOrderedList<Event> C) {
        // create arraylist
        ArrayList<String> sortedList  = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (true) {
            GOrderedList<Event> first = C.getNext();
            if (first == null) {
                break;
            }
            String highest = first.getValue().getname();
            sortedList .add(highest);
        }
        Collections.sort(sortedList , new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String f1, String f2) {
                return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
            }
        });

        return sortedList ;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code:

1. Calling `getNext()` in the while loop will increment and skip a value each time. You probably need to call a `hasNext()` method.
2. Each iteration of the outer loop needs to add its element in the proper position. As written, the value added is always going to be at the end.

As previously  mentioned  there are standard ways to do this, but my assumption  is  that you need to do this as an exercise. If not, use a Comparator. String's natural comparison may give you exactly  what you want.

Comment: For 1., if I guessed correctly at the `GOrderedList`, `getNext()` does not advance, just returns a reference to the next node (or null). For 2., if the list is already ordered, as the class name suggests, this is only an issue if a different ordering is desired. I wish the OP would tell us.

Comment: You're right in that getNext() does not advance and only returns the reference. The list is already ordered, and cannot be reordered in itself - but needs to be printed in alphabetical order, hence the question. I had the idea of placing the elements in the new ArrayList in alphabetical order. I could place the items in the ArrayList and then sort it, but I would rather not do that.